# .NET Web API 2 - Generate Model & Controller from Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to get familiar with .NET and Web API 2 and I have been reading tutorials and building test projects for the past couple of days.

What I want to do now is to utilize an existing database (MSSQL DB) that I have from a previous project with a new Web API 2 project. But what I can't figure out is how to build the model classes and controllers from the existing database.

I have read around the subject without success. Any help or guidance regarding this would be truly appreciated.

I have included a screen-shot of what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

Comment: @Donal - Hi, I have tried that tutorial and this one http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1. What I am trying to understand is how to create Web API 2 model classes and controller from the existing db. Or maybe I am just not getting it. :/

Comment: @MercuryTerminal The top comment is the correct one that describes how you can easily use "The database first" approach. When you do this you will already have the auto-generated models.